# long delays in php code execution when deleting files in directory with many files

Tags: php

I have a "cleanup script" removing images from file system, that are not present in an array.
When using it with an array of 300 file names and 60.000 unique files in my directory, it deletes all 59.700 unwanted files within 10 seconds.
In a bigger scenario with 860.000 files and an array of 600 file names the script becomes much slower, but I can not figure out, why.

```
$start = microtime(true);
$keepMe = ["file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", ......... ]; // files i want to keep, loaded from mysql database
print count($keepMe ) . " files should be left after cleanup \n";
$files = glob("/my/directory/*");
print (microtime(true)-$start)."s - " . count($files) . " files in directory \n";

$removed = 0;
foreach ($files as $_f)
{
    if (in_array(basename($_f), $keepMe)) continue;

    unlink($_f);
    $removed++;
    if( $removed%500 == 0 ) print (microtime(true)-$start)."s - {$removed} files removed \n";
    if(microtime(true) - $start > 20) break;
}
 print (microtime(true)-$start)."s - {$removed} files removed in total";
```

I print the current script execution time every 500 removed files and the script stops after 20 seconds (just for performance comparison).
Here is the output i get:

> 860 files should be left after cleanup
>   1.6677060127258s - 385626 files in directory
>   1.679957151413s - 500 files removed
>   1.7079961299896s - 1000 files removed
>   ... i will skip some
>   2.7962679862976s - 10000 files removed
>   2.8500139713287s - 10500 files removed
>   23.64742398262s - 10093 files removed in total

originally i started with ~580.000 images in one directory, after running and debugging this script multiple times, i'm at ~385.000 files but its not getting any faster.
In most cases (like 90%) it removed 10k-11k images, but sometimes there were just 300.
There is a strange 20 seconds gap (usually its between 10 and 15) before the last total count output.
And at this point i have no idea what happens there and why.
I used this script in ~ 70 directories with 30k-60k images each and had no problems, but there are 5 diredctories with 500k-600k images each, where throubles started.
Same server, same php version.
After those troubles I executed my script it a smaller directory again and it was fine, so there is no hardware throttling. Unfortunately i can't test it on another server (actually I'm cleaning it up to move to another server).

any ideas?

Comment: It takes time to process files. If you have more files it is normal to take longer.

Comment: One thing to try is to comment out things like `unlink($_f);` and see how this affects the run-time.

Comment: @NigelRen without actually deleting files, it checks 210k files in 20 seconds without any gaps between outputs. Since ``unlink()`` is not supposed to be asynchronous, i wonder, what happens in 10-15 seconds between the final output